# How to get a specific HTML tags

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get a HTML tags if the item has no text.
For instance: I am looping through all the "a" attributes(URL).
However, some of the URL has text in it and some don't.
In this case I'm trying to get the URL for the ones that don't have text on it.
Therefore, I did something like this.

```
response = requests.get('https://fw.tmall.com/tmall/ser/tmall_detail.htm?spm=a1z1g.2177293.0.0.qF9gPO&service_code=ts-4078').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
main_wrapper = soup.find('div',attrs={'id':'success-case'}).findAll('a')
for items in main_wrapper:
    dictionary = {}
    href = items['href']
    if items.string is None:
        print items['href']
    else:
        print items.string
```

How do I do it so that `if items.string is None:` get that item specific URL only and not all the URL?

Comment: Can you try to clarify? What are you getting? What do you want to get?

Comment: I want to get specific HTML attribute, in this case it would be IMG URL that's inside <a> if that <a> element has no text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the URL for the ones that don't have text on it

You could use list-comprehension

```
hrefs = [a['href'] for a in main_wrapper if a.string is None]
```

> get that item specific url only and not all the URL!

Not clear what that means. Each `a` tag only has one, specific URL. You are iterating over a list of `a` tags, therefore you get a list of URLs

> I want to get specific HTML attribute, in this case it would be IMG URL that's inside `<a>`

Then you need another `find` method within the loop to extract out that `<img>` element to get the `src` attribute

Comment: Welcome. You can use the checkmark next to the post to show your thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to get the unique anchors from the *unordered list* inside your *div*. You can see each anchor has a unique class, `rel-ink` vs `rel-name`:

```
 <a href="//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2469022358" target="_blank" class="rel-ink"><img alt="NIHAOMARKET官方海外旗舰店" src="//img.alicdn.com/top/i1/TB1urimJFXXXXabaXXXwu0bFXXX.png" class="rel-img"></a>
 <a href="//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2469022358" target="_blank" class="rel-name">NIHAOMARKET官方海外旗舰店</a>
```

So  you can use the anchor class name for the first anchor inside each *li*  i.e *rel-ink* to get them:

```
urls =[a["href"] for a in soup.find('div', id="success-case").find_all("a",class_="rel-ink")]
```

Or using a *css selector*:

```
urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select("#success-case ul li a.rel-ink")]
```

Both will give you:

```
['//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=692020965', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2087799889', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2469022358', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=377676745', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2367059695', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=449764134', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=698389964', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=509711360', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=692020965', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=1125022434', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=1071997040', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=795947607', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=509711360', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=692020965', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=1071997040', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=509711360', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=377676745', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2367059695', '//store.taobao.com/shop/view_shop.htm?user_number_id=2469022358']
```